# Calling apply template on a variable value in xslt

Tags: .net, xslt, xslt-1.0

In my xslt, I am calling external code to assign a node set to a xslt variable. I would now like to apply template on this node set.

```
<xsl:variable name="var1" select="ExtObject:GetNodeSet()"/>
```

So far I have seen that templates can be applied to input xml document. But can I parse the xml assigned to `var1` with apply templates and reflect the result in the output document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just use

```
<xsl:variable name="$var1" select="ExtObject:GetNodeSet()"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:apply templates select="$var1"/>
```

This works because the variable retains all type information, so the correct template can be found.